# on ng-click parameter not passed correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am passing a binded parameter to a function on ng-click like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="follwing in following.Users">
    <a href="" ng-click="unfollow({{follwing.ID}})">Un-follow</a>
</li>
```

This is causing the error below:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'follwing.ID' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 12 of the expression [unfollow({{follwing.ID}})] starting at [follwing.ID}})].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.10/$parse/syntax?p0=follwing.ID&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=12&p3=unfollow(%7B%7Bfollwing.ID%7D%7D)&p4=follwing.ID%7D%7D)
    at http://localhost/mb-www2015/js/angular.v1.2.10.js:78:12
    at Parser.throwError (http://localhost/mb-www2015/js/angular.v1.2.10.js:9884:11)
    at Parser.consume (http://localhost/mb-www2015/js/angular.v1.2.10.js:9921:12)
```

And when I add single quotations around `{{follwing.ID}}` like:

```
<a href="" ng-click="unfollow('{{follwing.ID}}')">Un-follow</a>
```

It passes the string `{{follwing.ID}}` as is, instead of its value.

Also need to change text and the calling function from unfollow to follow. How can I access the anchor tag clicked, from unfollow function ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: try: `ng-click="unfollow(follmasjid.ID)"`. you don't need `{{}}`

Comment: Done It. Thanks for the quick help.

Comment: @Fahad u have a spelling mistake too . `follwing` and `following.ID`

Comment: @MaximShoustin: What do you mean by follmasjid. Are you trying to convey something hidden here.

Comment: @iJay That was typo while changing the original variable to temp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be enough :

```
<li ng-repeat="follwing in following.Users">
    <a href="" ng-click="unfollow(following.ID)">Un-follow</a>
</li>
```

[ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick#usage) expects an [expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

Comment: @MaximShoustin As per your comment, added a brief explanation redirecting to official angularjs documentation.

Comment: How can I access the anchor tag clicked, from unfollow function ?

Comment: @Fahad try `ng-click="unfollow(following.ID,this)"`

Comment: @Fahad Accessing DOM from the controller is definitely [*not* a good practice](http://blog.nebithi.com/angularjs-dos-and-donts/).

Comment: @FlorianF. Thanks, is there an alternative ?

Comment: Usually, DOM is accessed through [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). But it mostly depends on what you wanna achieve.

Answer (score 2):

There is 1 mistake

1. curly brace not needed in `ng-click`

Here is the modified code :

```
<li ng-repeat="following in following.Users">
    <a href="" ng-click="unfollow(following.ID)">Un-follow</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can't use the curly {{}} bracket in ng-click.

```
<a href="" ng-click="unfollow(following.ID)">Un-follow</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Everything between {{SOME_EXPRESSION_HERE}} expression is evaluated with $eval.

2) Everything inside in native angular directive is evaluated becouse is expression.

In your case "unfollow(following.ID)" unfollow is function defined in your $scope.

When click event is triggered, angular $eval's your expression and see JavaScript code or 'unfollow()' function in your case.

The 'following' is already defined by 'ng-repeat' directive and bind it as parameter to 'unfollow' function.

Then your function is called with following.ID parameter. If function doesn't exist, nothing's gonna happen (carefully).